# Filtering mongo data by sub json field (mongosh)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

Suppose I have a mongo collection that looks like this:

```
{
_id: ...,
timestamp: '',
SomeStuff: {},
OriginalData: '{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 23,
'}
}
```

This represents a single record in this collection. Everything in the OriginalData field was populated by a source json object converted to a string. Everything else is something that some standardized process inserts automatically (and can safely assume is always present)

Is it possible to filter this collection in a way that I can operate on the subfields in OriginalData?

Something like:

```
# Find all the records with people who are 20 years or older
mongosh> col.find({'OriginalData.age': {$gte: 20}})
```

I want to filter based on a numeric sub-field and also take into account that maybe some originalData fields may not supply the age field.

Comment: Is there something that is wrong or doesn't work about the query you've provided?

Comment: It returns nothing. Again, OriginalData is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should fix that issue by saving it as document, instead of string. But, in the meanwhile you can use [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/function/) to convert it into document and then filter it.

```
db.col.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      newField: {
        $function:{
          body: function(OriginalData) {  //js function that parses the string and returns document
            return JSON.parse(OriginalData)
          },
          args: ["$OriginalData"],    //string field is the argument to the js function
          lang: "js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {"newField.age": {$gte: 20}}
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you! This works. I wrapped the body function in a try catch to handle invalid json. What does this aggregate actually return? How do I limit/sort/countDocuments on the return value?

Comment: You can add as many [stages](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) as you like.
[$limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-limit), [$sort](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/), [count](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/count/)

Comment: Thanks. So now that I actually have it working, can you point me to some documentation that explains the difference between find() and aggregate()? I don't understand what's happening well enough to know if I'm missing records because of whatever aggregate does.